Should i stain this raw cedar siding? Rain and winter temps are coming
Not sure if this is the right place but hoping for some perspective.
I had a siding project get delayed and it's now ready for stain. It's Friday night we are expecting rain on Monday night and freezing cold afterwards. The siding is moist, reading 17-18% right now. I'm expecting the humidity to drop tonight/tomorrow with 50 degree temps, the wood temp is currently 45-50 (the stain says 40+ recommended).
I see two options and don't really know the pros or cons of either.  Currently planning to stain tomorrow, I plan to re-stain next year either way
Option 1. Stain it tomorrow around noon, let it cure until Monday afternoon and then cover with a tarp to protect it from rain/weather and hope that it cures okay. I can give the siding breathing room with the tarp, it won't be pressed against
Option 2. Do not stain at all - I'm not sure if or how i could protect the wood if i don't stain. Would the siding be ruined if no stain for a 6 month Minnesota winter? Advice on this would be amazing, i just don't know.
I am prepared to stain tomorrow, have a air sprayer and an oil stain - ultra 7. I just don't know what makes the most sense.
Thanks for making it this far. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions and advice.



Cedar does not need to be stained or painted unless you want to change the color.  It is naturally resistant to water and, left alone, fades to a gray shade, IIRC.

Thank you for this. I will not stain it and will wait until til next summer
